# Firestore security rules - Is it possible to restrict data access when using custom auth

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm developing app for University. I will give each student a unique 10 digit Id for login(no email and password, student can just login using the given id). Now I need to restrict student to access only their data, not other students data. In firestore security rules is it possible with my implementation?

In PHP MySQL I can check it in the script, in Firebase it is still possible if I use cloud functions for all read and write operations. Is it is good practice to use cloud functions for all read and write operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you [mint a custom token for your users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), Firebase Authentication will know about the user, and pass the information into the security rules of your database. Without such a custom token, there is no way to pass your information into security rules.